# How to get selected radio button value which contains objects when button click in parameter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get the selected radio button value when button click. I am using ajax to populate the radio button options and I want to get selected radio button value when button click. I am tried passing parameter to ng-click function. It used to work incase of select option but below code for radio button didnot worked.

I am using Angular v1.

### Angular JS

```
 $scope.modify_pnr = function (obj) {

            vm.ssr_details = [];
            vm.name_number = [];
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                data: $.param({action: "modify_pnr", pnr: obj.target.attributes.data.value, security: ajax_object.ajax_nonce}),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function (response) {
                    vm.ssr_details = response.modify_pnr;
                    vm.name_number = response.link_number;
                    vm.foraddssr = response.foraddssr;
                    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("modify_ssr_main").style.display = "block";
            });
        };

  $scope.add_ssr = function (obj, details) {
            alert(details);         //got undefined.
        };
```

### HTML

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div ng-repeat = "user in data.foraddssr" class="modify_ssr_segment_select">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="details" name="details" value="{carrier : '{{user.carrier}}', segment_no: '{{user.RPH}}'}">

        <!-- Here radio button value in object --!>

        <div>{{user.from}}  &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp; {{user.to}}<br><br>
            <span class="sprite-img pull-left" style="background-position: <?= get_airline_logo("{{user.carrier}}"); ?>;margin-right: 10px;"></span>
            <div class="pull-left">
               <?php $a = get_airline_name("{{user.carrier}}");
                     echo $a['name'];
               ?><br>
               Default Meal : {{user.default_meal}}
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"> 
         <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="add_ssr($event,details)" ng-model="add_ssr">Add</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Check the answer, it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value= 'foo';
    $scope.changedValue= 'foo';
    
    $scope.newValue = function(value) {
       $scope.changedValue = value;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
foo
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="foo" ng-change='newValue(value)'>
ben
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="ben" ng-change='newValue(value)'>
Jack
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="Jack" ng-change='newValue(value)'>    
<hr> 
This value is set from ng-change <b>{{changedValue}}</b>
</div>
```

This working code will help you integrate in your code. You simply need to add a `ng-change` here

```
 <input type="radio" ng-model="details" name="details" value="{carrier : '{{user.carrier}}', segment_no: '{{user.RPH}}'}" ng-change='newValue(details)'>
```

Then add a function `newValue` in your controller same as above. Then you will get the changed value when you select radio button.

Also if you want the entire `user` object when radio button changes then you can pass the `user` object as a parameter to `ng-change` like this in HTML

```
ng-change='newValue(user)'
```

Then on the `$scope.newValue` function you can manipulate the `user` object and access it's properties.